# How to get rid of "Failed to determine definition for Feature with ID"

Tags: sharepoint, moss

My event logs on my production front end servers are getting filled with error messages:

"Failed to determine definition for Feature with ID"

Now, I've found the offending feature on one of the development servers - it is an InfoPath form with some code behind.  But, it is nowhere to be found on the production servers.

I've tried running the following command on the production servers:
stsadm -o uninstallfeature -id (your GUID) -force

There was no change - the error is still being generated.

How do I get rid of the error?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure but I think copying that feature definition to the production's 12/TEMPLATES/FEATURES and then uninstalling it may help.

But it is not clear from this error message "Failed to determine definition for Feature with ID" what part of your production system is tied to the feature and what action is performed which leads to this error. Increasing the verbosity of Sharepoint logs could help you to more precisely determine what exactly causes the error.

Answer (score 0):

Try this: [SharePoint Feature Administration and Clean Up Tool](http://featureadmin.codeplex.com/)

> Find faulty FeatureDefinitions and cleanly uninstall them.
>   Find Feature remainders in Sites, SiteCollections, WebApps and in the Farm, from e.g. forcefully uninstalled Features from farm without deactivating them before, causing errors.
>   Also, de-/activate Features Farm wide.